# unsubscribe monthly recurring payment?

Tags: php, paypal, cakephp-2.0, payment-gateway, payment

I am using cakephp 2.0 framework. Can anyone help me what i am doing wrong here i have unsubscribe function
[image]

```
 public function unsubscribe() {
    if(isset($_POST['user_id']) && !empty($_POST['user_id'])){
        $this->loadModel('PaypalSinglePayment');
        $this->loadModel('PaypalRecurringPayment');
        $userDetails = $this->PaypalSinglePayment->find('first', array(
            'conditions'=> array(
                'user_id'=>$_POST['user_id'],
                'payment_type'=>"Month"
                )
            )
        );            
        if(!empty($userDetails))
        {            
            $profile_id=urlencode($userDetails['PaypalSinglePayment']['subscriber_id']);            
            $profileID=urlencode($profile_id);
            $action = urlencode('Cancel');
            $nvpStr="&PROFILEID=$profileID&ACTION=$action"; 
            $paypal = new PaypalPro(['live'=>1]);
            $resArray=$paypal->hashCall("ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus",$nvpStr);
            $ack = strtoupper((string)$resArray["ACK"]); 
            if($ack=="SUCCESS"){ 
            $this->PaypalSinglePayment->id = $userDetails['PaypalSinglePayment']['id'];
            $data['payment_status'] = "Cancel";

            if($this->PaypalSinglePayment->save($data)){
              echo json_encode(array(
                          'status'=>'Success',
                          'responseCode'=>1
                       ) 
                   );
              die;
            }
            }
            else{
              echo json_encode( array('msg' => 'Something went wrong, please try again','status'=>'Error Occured','responseCode'=>0) );
              die;
            }             
        }
    }
    echo json_encode( array('msg' => 'Something went wrong, please try again','status'=>'Error Occured','responseCode'=>0) );
    die;
}
```

whenver i send user_id in Unscubscribe function it goes to else condition here i have successfully get the subscriber_id. Can anyone help me What i am doing wrong
Here is the hashcallFunction

```
enter code here
public function hashCall($methodName,$nvpStr){
    // form header string
    $nvpheader = $this->nvpHeader();

    //setting the curl parameters.
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$this->apiEndpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

    //turning off the server and peer verification(TrustManager Concept).
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    //in case of permission APIs send headers as HTTPheders
    if(!empty($this->authToken) && !empty($this->authSignature) && !empty($this->authTimestamp))
     {
        $headers_array[] = "X-PP-AUTHORIZATION: ".$nvpheader;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers_array);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    }
    else 
    {
        $nvpStr = $nvpheader.$nvpStr;
    }
    //if USE_PROXY constant set to TRUE in Constants.php, then only proxy will be enabled.
   //Set proxy name to PROXY_HOST and port number to PROXY_PORT in constants.php 
    if($this->useProxy)
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $this->proxyHost.":".$this->proxyPort); 

    //check if version is included in $nvpStr else include the version.
    if(strlen(str_replace('VERSION=', '', strtoupper($nvpStr))) == strlen($nvpStr)) {
        $nvpStr = "&VERSION=" . urlencode($this->version) . $nvpStr;    
    }

    $nvpreq="METHOD=".urlencode($methodName).$nvpStr;
    //setting the nvpreq as POST FIELD to curl
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$nvpreq);

    //getting response from server
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    //convrting NVPResponse to an Associative Array
    $nvpResArray = $this->deformatNVP($response);
    $nvpReqArray = $this->deformatNVP($nvpreq);
    $_SESSION['nvpReqArray']=$nvpReqArray;

    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        die("CURL send a error during perform operation: ".curl_error($ch));
    } else {
        //closing the curl
        curl_close($ch);
    }

    return $nvpResArray;
}
```

Comment: You should always try to use cake's structure while using the framework. For starters, you'd access the data as `$this->request->data['Model']['attribute']`. Have you checked (printed) what the first find is getting? Have you confirmed your `user_id` is getting there right?

Answer (score 0):

You may not have any record in paypal_single_payments table with user_id=24 and payment_type = "Month".
Also you could try to debug the content of the $_POST and $userDetails 
variable to see if they are not empty.
I agree with SrQ that you should use the the Cake's data structure, and the $this->request->data to access the post variables.